# Is intensity of sinusoidal EM radiation equal to or just proportional to the amplitude squared?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

In section 29.4 of Volume I of the Feynman Lectures we are told:

> "By the intensity we mean the amount of energy that the field carries past us per second, which is proportional to the square of the field, averaged in time."

But in section 29.5 he says, regarding the superposition of two waves:

> "Thus the sum of the two effects has the intensity $A_1^2$ we would get with one of them alone, plus the intensity $A_2^2$ we would get with the other one alone, plus a correction."

In equations 30.2 and 30.3 he does the same thing again.  Amplitude is given as

$$A_R=A\frac{\sin n\phi/2}{\sin \phi/2}$$

> "The resultant intensity is thus "

$$I=I_0\frac{\sin n\phi/2}{\sin \phi/2}.$$

Where $I_0$ is the intensity for the case of $n=1$.

The same thing was done in the exercises.  Is this use of the term "intensity" as the square of the magnitude technically incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term *intensity* tends to be rather loosely used, and in optics there are a whole range of ways of specifying the *brightness* of the light.

However if we take the intensity to the simply the power per unit area, i.e. the number of joules per second per square metre carried by the electromagnetic wave, then the power is given by:

$$ W = \frac{E^2}{2\eta_0} $$

where $E$ is the amplitude of the electric field associated with the EM wave and $\eta_0$ is the [impedance of free space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impedance_of_free_space).

So Feynman is correct when he says:

> By the intensity we mean the amount of energy that the field carries past us per second, which is proportional to the square of the field, averaged in time

the constant of proportionality being $1/\eta_0$.